# Socket won't bind: no such device

Tags: python, sockets

So I have this piece of Python 3 code:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
s.bind(('eth0', 0))
s.send(eth_packet)
```

This code works on my Raspberry Pi, but not on my external server. When I try to run it on my external server i get:

```
# sudo python3 test.py
s.send(eth_packet)
socket.error: [Errno 19] No such device
```

And I checked the network interfaces output (via an python script):
External server (debian):

```
['lo [index=1, IPv4=127.0.0.1, IPv6=::1]', 'eth0:0 [index=2, IPv4=xxxxx, IPv6=None]', 'eth0 [index=2, IPv4=yyyyyy, IPv6=zzzzzzz]']
```

Raspberry pi:

```
['lo [index=1, IPv4=127.0.0.1, IPv6=None]', 'eth0 [index=2, IPv4=rrrrr, IPv6=None]']
```

Can someone explain what is going on? I just want to send a handcrafted message but this error keeps bugging me, can this be a problem with the drivers of my server? This is the same result as ifconfig.

**Edit**

Ok, i used strace for this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket
import binascii
import struct

test= '000a959d6816'
packet= struct.pack("!6s", binascii.unhexlify(bytes(test, 'UTF-8')))
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
s.bind(('eth0', 0))
s.send(packet)
```

And this is the important part about strace:

```
socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, 0)          = 3
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFINDEX, {ifr_name="eth0", ifr_index=2}) = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, proto=0000, if2, pkttype=PACKET_HOST, addr(0)={0, }, 20) = 0
sendto(3, "\0\n\225\235h\26", 6, 0, NULL, 0) = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
open("test.py", O_RDONLY)               = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=247, ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7fff86c5f090) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=247, ...}) = 0
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
dup(4)                                  = 5
fcntl(5, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=247, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fc1251c2000
lseek(5, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
read(5, "#!/usr/bin/env python3\n\nimport s"..., 4096) = 247
close(5)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fc1251c2000, 4096)            = 0
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
read(4, "#!/usr/bin/env python3\n\nimport s"..., 4096) = 247
close(4)                                = 0
write(2, "Traceback (most recent call last"..., 143Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    s.send(packet)
socket.error: [Errno 6] No such device or address
) = 143
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fc1264050a0}, {0x428787, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fc1264050a0}, 8) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
```

Comment: Do `eth0:0` or `lo` work in the Debian machine?

Comment: eth0:0 does not work either.

Comment: The interface name passed to bind (in this case, "eth0") is looked up by ioctl() SIOCGIFINDEX.  You should post the output of strace.  The relevant parts of my strace look like this: socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, 0)          = 3
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFINDEX, {ifr_name="eth0", ifr_index=2}) = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, proto=0000, if2, pkttype=PACKET_HOST, addr(0)={0, }, 20) = 0

Comment: Do you see eth0 when you do ifconfig?

Comment: The code works on Ubuntu. Does `socket.if_nametoindex('eth0')` raise an error?

Comment: You may just have insufficient privileges to do that.

Comment: In your original question you showed the error was errno 19 (ENODEV).  But your strace is showing errno 6 (ENXIO).  Did something change?  (Also, the title of this is "won't bind", but the error is on send(), not bind().)  FWIW, your example works fine for me on Xubuntu with 3.13.0 kernel.  What distribution and kernel version is this on?  What version of python 3 is on both?  In other words, identify what's different between the Pi and the other machine.

Answer (score 6):

When you bind a RAW socket with family PACKET on an interface, you need a tuple with 2 objects:

```
(interfaceName, protoNumber)
```

or 5 objects:

```
(interfaceName, protoNumber, pkttype, hatype, haddr)
```

You specify 0 in protoNumber but maybe protoNumber 0 doesn't exist in your system.

[Documentation about packet family: packet(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html)

> **sll_protocol** is the standard ethernet protocol type in network byte
>   order as defined in the  include file.

Try to find the right protocol number in *linux/if_ether.h*.

Comment: Did somebody find the right protocoll number from that file? I tried 6, 2, 14 and 60 (and 3) from the first section (Ubuntu 18.04) but I am not sure if I even got the section right. The original code used a "0" and was written for Windows: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your external server runs under Linux, there are some reasons not to be able to run your program.

As already noted by Figus, you actually use protocol number 0, which may not be defined. You could be more lucky with :

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, proto)
```

where `proto` is the protocol number corresponding to ETH_P_ALL in linux/if_ether.h (3 on some Linux boxes)

But `man packet` also says : *Only processes with effective UID 0 or the CAP_NET_RAW capability may open packet sockets*. So it means you must have root privileges on your external server to run your code.

Comment: I tried `ETH_P_ALL` (3) on my Ubuntu 18.04 with sudo and this did not work. `Error: No such device`.

Answer (score -3):

this is a client that can send a handcrafted message. the variables ip and port are the port and ip address of your server the values in the below program are examples

```
import socket
ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 447
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((ip, port))
msg = ("hello ex. message")
s.send(msg.encode('ascii'))
rep = s.recv(1024)
rep1 = (rep.decode('ascii'))
print rep1
```

and the server is

```
import socket
ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 447
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((ip, port))
s.listen(15)
con, addr = s.accept()
msg = con.recv(1024)
msg1 = (msg.decode('ascii'))
print (msg1)
rep = ("got message")
con.send(rep.encode('ascii'))
```

I hope this answer helps and this is what your looking for.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the above question, which is about raw sockets.